# Minimal Least Common Multiplier for $n$ distinct integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, least-common-multiple

Let $n\in\mathbb N^+$ be a positive integer.

I am trying to find a set of $n$ distinct positive integers with minimal LCM.

- **What is the set of $n$ distinct integers with minimal LCM?**
- **What is the asymptotics of this LCM as a function of $n$?**

---

Observe that we can choose the set to be $\{1,...,n\}$, which would give a bound of $2^{O(n)}$. However, I'm not sure that this is tight.

For example, if $n=9$ then LCM$(\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\})=2520$, but we have

LCM$(\{1,2,3,4,6,8,12,16,24\})=48$.

Answer (score 3):

ADDED: see [Nicolas on highly composite](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/hcnrevisited.pdf)

[Nicolas  Full List](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/publications.html)

you can get a predictably small LCM by taking the first Superior Highly Composite Number with number of divisors at least your target number, you are calling that $n$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superior_highly_composite_number

For your $7 \leq n \leq 12,$ you can get a small LCM by taking $n$ divisors of $60$

For your $13 \leq n \leq 16,$ you can get a small LCM by taking $n$ divisors of $120$

For your $17 \leq n \leq 24,$ you can get a small LCM by taking $n$ divisors of $360$

For your $25 \leq n \leq 48,$ you can get a small LCM by taking $n$ divisors of $2520$

Comment: Thanks for the direction! Given that this is not tight (e.g., for $n=9$ we can get LCM=48 as in the example above), do you know how well it approximates the minimal LCM? What is the asymptotic growth of it?

Comment: @RB one can look that up; the advantage of the SHC numbers is simply that there is a fixed recipe for constructing them. To get the best from your viewpoint, you need to widen a little bit to the highly composite numbers,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Given $n$ integers
$$
a_{\,1} ,a_{\,2} , \cdots ,a_{\,n} 
$$
having the prime factorization
$$
a_{\,k}  = p_{\,1} ^{\,b_{\,1,\;k} } p_{\,2} ^{\,b_{\,2,\;k} } \; \cdots \;p_{\,q} ^{\,b_{\,q,\;k} } 
$$
then the factorization of their LCM will have exponents which are the "envelope" , i.e.the maximum
of the exponents for each prime
$$
\eqalign{
  & LCM\left( {a_{\,1} ,a_{\,2} , \cdots ,a_{\,n} } \right) = p_{\,1} ^{\,\max \left( {b_{\,1,\;k} } \right)} p_{\,2} ^{\max \left( {\,b_{\,2,\;k} } \right)} \; 
  \cdots \;p_{\,q} ^{\max \left( {\,b_{\,q,\;k} } \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = 2^{\,l_{\,1} \,m_{\,1}  + l_{\,2} \,m_{\,2}  + \; \cdots  + l_{\,q} \,m_{\,q} } \quad \left| \matrix{
  \;l_{\,j}  = \log _2 p_{\,j}  \hfill \cr 
  \;m_{\,j}  = \max \left( {\,b_{\,j,\;k} \left| {\;1 \le k \le n} \right.} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$

Now, taking the integers to be consecutive powers of $2$ we have
$$
\left( {2^{\,0} ,2^{\,1} , \cdots ,2^{\,n - 1} } \right)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  d = No.\,of\,digits = n \hfill \cr 
  \log _2 LCM = n - 1 \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
while adding a $3$
$$
\left( {\matrix{
   {2^{\,0} ,} & {2^{\,1} ,} & { \cdots ,} & {2^{\,n - 1} ,}  \cr 
   {2^{\,0} 3,} & {2^{\,1} 3} & { \cdots ,} & {2^{\,n - 1} 3}  \cr 
 } } \right)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  d = No.\,of\,digits = 2n \hfill \cr 
  \log _2 LCM = n - 1 + \log _2 3 \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

That means that taking  the products of the first q primes,
with all the combinations of the exponents of each 
varying from $0$ to a given maximum $m_k$, we get
$$
Comb.\left( {p_{\,1} ^{\,0, \cdots ,m_{\,1} } p_{\,2} ^{\,0, \cdots ,m_{\,2} } \; \cdots \;p_{\,q} ^{\,0, \cdots ,m_{\,q} } } \right)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  D = \log _2 No.\,of\,digits = \log _2 n = \sum\limits_k {\log _2 \left( {1 + m_{\,k} } \right)}  \hfill \cr 
  L = \log _2 LCM = \sum\limits_k {l_{\,k} \,m_{\,k} }  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
and given $D$ to minimize $L$ (or v.v. given $L$ to maximize $D$), wrt  the variables $m_k$.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're suggesting here. How many powers of 3 will you take? (do you mean to choose it as $k$ for which $k\log_2 3 = n$ where $n$ is the number of powers of $2$)? of 5? is there a constructive way of doing that? How does the resulting LCM grow as a function of $n$?

Comment: @RB if you associate $m$ powers of $3$ ($0,\cdots,m-1$) you get $d=mn, \; \log _2 LCM = n - 1 +(m-1) \log _2 3$. Similarly adding $5,7$ etc.

Comment: @RB  I learned this area from a 1988 article by Jean-Louis Nicolas, http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/hcnrevisited.pdf   and all his publications listed with links: http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/publications.html

Comment: @WillJagy: thanks, interesting links: now the grounds of your answer are quite clear (they were not clear to me in the first version of your answer).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm wondering if there's an analytic solution for this problem or a reasonable way to evaluate your suggestion. It seems that even for small $n$, this would be quite expensive computationally (i.e., we replaced my minimization problem with an optimization problem that I'm not sure is easier to solve).

Comment: @RB My answer is the introductory background which brings the problem into the field of *Highly Composite Numbers*, and *Superior Highly Composite Numbers*
as per W. Jagy's answer.

Comment: @GCab neat idea, however it seems that this is restricted to the case when $n=\prod_{k=1}^q(1+m_k)$ and this can be restrictive in some applications. An obvious solution is to take all the possible combinations, not just those defined by the cartesian grid, however this can make the optimization infeasible since ${\prod_{k=1}^q(1+m_k) \choose q}$ will grow very quickly...